# how to map 500 error in urlmappings file?

Tags: grails, grails3

In order to test mapping 500 status in urlmappings file. The goal is to display the custom error view page. I have intentionally thrown exception to test this.

I have setup this simple code.

```
import java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException

class HomeController {

    def index() {

        throw new AccessDeniedException('asd')
    }
}
```

I map 500 code in urlmappings

```
package exceptiontest
import java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException

class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

        "/"(controller: 'home', action: 'index')
        "404"(view:'/notFound')

        "500"(controller: "errors", action: "error403")

    }
}
```

Here is errors controller

```
package exceptiontest

class ErrorsController {

    def error403() {}

}
```

Here is error403.gsp file

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Access denied!</title>
    <meta name='layout' content='main' />
</head>

<body>
<h1>Access Denied</h1>
<p>We're sorry, but you are not authorized
to perform the requested operation.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

It doesn't display this error view. What am i missing to make this urlmappings work for 500 code? I appreciate any help. Thanks!

I am using Grails 3.3.8.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting a 500 error or are you getting a 403?  Try adding a 403 to your URL mappings or try the following in your controller to get a 500 error.

import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.*

render status: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR